# Do we have $(G/H)\times H \cong G$ for groups in general?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

After some thought I began to suspect $(G/H)\times H \cong G$, so I tried to construct an isomorphism by hand. I came up with $\varphi: (gH, h) \mapsto gh$ which came out to work provided $G$ is abelian. I can't think of anything if $G$ isn't abelian, but I'm pretty convinced it's true. How else can one prove isomorphism? (perhaps more importantly is this actually true; of course my difficulty would be easiest explained if this is false!)

Edit: Outline of my 'proof':

$\varphi((gH,h))(fH,k)) = \varphi((gH,h))\varphi((fH,k)) = ghfk$ and $\varphi((gH,h)(fH,k)) = \varphi((gfH,hk)) = gfhk$. Hence $\varphi$ is multiplicative iff $G$ abelian.

Next, $(gH,h)^{-1} = (g^{-1}H, h^{-1})$, so $\varphi((gH,h)^{-1}) = \varphi((g^{-1}H, h^{-1})) = g^{-1}h^{-1} = (hg)^{-1} = (gh)^{-1} = \varphi((gH,h))^{-1}$. This again relied on $G$ being abelian, and shows that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

Now $\varphi(gH,h) = 1 \iff g=1$ and $h=1$; so $\ker(\varphi)=(H,1)$ and so $\varphi$ is injective.

Lastly, $\varphi(gH,1)\mapsto g$ is a surjection onto $G-H$ and $\varphi(H,h)\mapsto h$ is a surjection onto $H$. Therefore the image of $\varphi$ is $G-H \cup H = G$

This is why I believe that I have an isomorphism; I would be grateful if you could point out its errors!

Comment: Note that $H$ would have to be normal for this to make sense.  However the statement is still not true.

Comment: @Seth Even if $H$ were normal, the isomorphism map in the proof is still not well defined

Comment: Your suspect is wrong. If $G$ is an indecomposable group, you can't have $G$ isomorphic to $G/H\times H$ unless $H$ is the trivial subgroup.

Comment: @Amr thanks but I just meant for the statement to make sense, not the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your proof is that $\phi : G/H \times H \rightarrow G$ is not a well-defined map.  If you set $\phi(gH,h) = gh$, then you must check that if $gH = g'H$, then $\phi(gH,h) = \phi(g'H,h)$, i.e. $gh = g'h$.  But it is easy to see this can be false in general.

For example, using Seth's example, suppose $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H = 2 \mathbb{Z}$.  Then taking $g = 0, g' = 2$, $0 + H = 2 + H$, but (taking $h = 0$), $0 + 0 \neq 2 + 0$.

Answer (score 5):

What you say you proved is not true 
( because your map is not well defined). Set $G=\mathbb{Z}_4$,$H=\{0,2\}$. $G\not\cong (G/H)\times H$. This is because $G$ has an element of order $4$, while $(G/H)\times H$ is actually isomorphic t0 $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ which does not have any element of order $4$.

Thus,  $(G/H)\times H \cong G$ is not even true for all abelian groups.

Comment: I just added the 'proof' of it being an isomorphism; Could you please take a look?

Comment: @FfireGarden Your isomorphism map is not well defined

Comment: I'm not sure how to see that; could you be more specific please?

Comment: @FireGarden when you say that you will send $(gH,h)$ to $gh$. Now it could happen that there are two distinct elements of $G$ $g_1,g_2$ such that $g_1H=g_2H$ (accordingly, $(g_1H,h)=(g_2H,h)$ (Ccall the last 2 equal ordered pairs $x$). Now will you send $x$ to $g_1H$ or to $g_2H$

Answer (score 5):

The statement is not true.

Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $H=2\mathbb{Z}$.

$\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}\times\mathbb{2Z} \neq \mathbb{Z}$ since the group on the left has torsion (a nonzero element of finite order).

Comment: You see, that really surprises me. Of course, you can describe every integer uniquely by specifying some integer multiple of 2 and whether to add one or not (e.g., (0,4) = 4, (1,-6) = -5, etc.) and addition works out: (0,4)+(1,-6)=(1,-2)=-1.. strange they are apparently not the same structure. Which element(s) have finite order? That isn't so clear to see for me..

Comment: Ah, but the definition of the group operation is component wise.  You could of course define a new group operation making these two sets isomorphic as you explained.  The nonzero element of finite order is $(1,0)$, because $(1,0)+(1,0)=(0,0)$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with non-abelian groups. Let $G=S_3$ and let $H=A_3$, the latter being the odd permutations. Then $$G/H \times H \approx \mathbb{Z}/2 \times A_3 \approx \mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/3$$

But this cannot happen, as $S_3$ is not abelian.

Comment: Nice, I noticed that If the statement was true then anytime a group $G$ had a normal subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ and $H$ are abelian we would have $G$ is abelian.  I figured this should give a wide class of counterexamples (for example letting $H$ be an abelian normal subgroup of prime index in a non abelian group).  Then I realized it isn't so easy to think of many groups with these properties.  (Or is it?)

Comment: @Seth: I think examples are easy to come by. Take the dihedral groups $D_n$. They all contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2$, generated by a rotation. The quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2$. So you have a countably infinite collection of counterexamples.

Comment: So they are easy to come by!  Thanks!